# What's the problem with an interop class as a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, com-interop

I have a generic base wrapper class to wrap a couple of com components we're using:

```
public class WrapperBase<T> : IDisposable
    where T : new()
{
    private T comObject = default(T);
    private ComponentParameters parameters = null;

    protected WrapperBase()
    {
        comObject = new T();
        Initialize();
    }

    public void SetParameters(ComponentParameters parameters)
    {
        // ...
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    // ... 
}
```

Now I have a concrete wrapper class which inherits from this base class:

```
public class UserWrapper : WrapperBase<CUserClass>
{
    public UserWrapper() : base() { }

    public void SomeUserWrapperMethod() 
    { 
        // ... 
    }
}
```

The type used (CUserClass) is a COM interop type. This type is available after adding the COM object as a reference to the project.

Now I use this class in another assembly (which references the assembly in which the above types are defined):

```
using (var user = new UserWrapper())
{
    user.SomeUserWrapperMethod();
}
```

The above code compiles fine, but if I'm actually calling the SetParameters method (which is only defined in the Wrapperbase class):

```
using (var user = new UserWrapper())
{
    user.SetParameters(someParameters);
}
```

I get a (double) compilation error:

> - error CS0012: The type 'ComponentsAssembly.CUserClass' is defined
>     in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>     'Interop.ComponentsAssembly,
>     Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>     PublicKeyToken=...'.
> - ComponentWrappers.dll: (Related file)
>     error CS0310: 'ComponentsAssembly.CUserClass' must be a
>     non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to
>     use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Contact.Wrappers.WrapperBase'

I've tried adding a reference to the component, but I still get the same error message.

This used to work before I changed the WrapperBase to a generic type, but then there was a lot of code identical in all the concrete wrappers, so I refactored it, making the WrapperBase generic in the process.

I can actually solve this by adding a constructor to the concrete class which takes a "ComponentParameters" as a parameter and calls the SetParameters internally:

```
public class UserWrapper : WrapperBase<CUserClass>
{
    public UserWrapper() : base() { }

    public UserWrapper(ComponentParameters parameters) : base()
    {
        SetParameters(parameters)
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
using (var user = new UserWrapper(someParameters))
{
    user.SomeUserWrapperMethod();
}
```

But I'd rather have both methods working (using a constructor and explicitly calling SetParameters).

Can anybody explain to me what exactly is happening here, as I've been banging my head against the wall for the last couple of hours.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, WrapperBase<> is defined in ComponentWrappers.dll assembly but you're actually using that generic in some sort of main program right?  You added the reference to the interop in the main program itself, and not COmponentWrapper.dll?

Comment: @James: Not exactly. Both WrapperBase<> and UserWrapper are in ComponentWrappers.dll and the com interop dll is only referenced in ComponentWrappers.dll. In the main program, I only use the UserWrapper class (and it references the ComponentWrappers.dll). But even if I add a reference to the interop dll in the main program, I still get the same compilation error.

Comment: Have you tried  adding a reference to the interop assembly to the main program..

Comment: Okay, yeah, you would need the reference in both (because of the base class bleeding) -- that is when you have public class UserWrapper : WrapperBase<CUserClass> visible any assembly calling it must know CUserClass too.  Hmmm.  Odd.  Were you adding the reference as interop in both?  Or did you add it as a COM reference in one and interop assembly reference in other?

Comment: To be clear: before WrapperBase was generic everything worked without the main program referencing the interop dll.

Comment: I added it as a COM reference. I didn't realize there was a difference with adding it as an "interop assembly". Can you elaborate on that and how exactly the 2 different methods are done?

Comment: That would make sense, then WrapperBase wouldn't bleed out the CUserClass...

Comment: Try the answer below and see if it works...  I think if you add it as a COM reference both times, each time it will generate an interop assembly (the .NET wrapper assembly for COM stuff) and it could be thinking those two are not identical.

Comment: Maybe you should favor composition over inheritance in that specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: when you add the COM reference in ComponentWrappers.dll, it generates an interop assembly for it and puts it in the build location (bin/release whatever) for that assembly.  In main, navigate to that location and add a a .NET reference (not COM reference) and navigate to that build location and take the interop as the reference.

I think it may be getting confused because you added it as COM in both places and it generated an interop in each...

The other option is to completely prevent the COM artifact from having any public visibility outside your assembly.  To do this you'd have to hide it internally in a class, etc.

Comment: (let me know if that doesn't make sense, I can elaborate further).  Essentially in ComponentWrappers.dll -> add COM reference, in main, add interop reference created in ComponentWrappers.dll's build location...

Comment: Ok, thanks! That actually did the trick (add reference, browse to build folder select actual interop dll). But I was wondering if there wasn't a way to prevent this. Also, won't this give problems in release build, when I select the interop dll from the debug folder, or the other way around?

Comment: Typically, when I've seen this done I've either seen people completely isolate the references to the COM class in one assembly so it doesn't bleed out, or have the interop be stored in a separate location.  You can generate an interop directly from the command line and then treat it like you would any other 3rd party assembly.  Or have a build step create it and place it in a given build location and then have both assemblies reference the interop directly.